# TCP Scan: Unexpected Socket Exceptions

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a simple TCP Port scanner. Here's my code:

```
for (int port : portList) {
    Socket socket = new Socket();

    try {
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(targetIP, port), 5000);

        // If we get to this point, port is open
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Port " + port + " open");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, e.toString());
    } finally {
        // Try to close
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Here's the debug output. I've run the scan several times and get the exact same output with the same port `ECONNREFUSED` while others `EHOSTUNREACH`.

```
D/TCPSCAN﹕ java.net.SocketException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.10 (port 21) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
D/TCPSCAN﹕ java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.10 (port 22) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
D/TCPSCAN﹕ java.net.SocketException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.10 (port 23) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
D/TCPSCAN﹕ java.net.SocketException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.10 (port 80) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
D/TCPSCAN﹕ java.net.SocketException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.10 (port 443) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
```

The Android device I'm running on can successfully `ping -c 1 -W 1 192.168.0.10`. My phone detects the remote host as online, which is why I don't understand why I'm getting `EHOSTUNREACH`. More curious is the fact that port 22 - which is not open on the target - gets a `ECONNREFUSED`.

The only port that is actually open on the target is FTP port 21 (confirmed with `nmap`).

I've read some answers to similar problems. The main fix seems to be restarting the phone's WiFi connection, which didn't work for me.

***Note***

For the sake of clarity I'm not posting my whole code here but I am checking that the target host `192.168.0.10` is online with:

```
Process process = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 -W 1 192.168.0.10");
// Wait until the process finishes and check exit code (0 for success)
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
if (exitCode == 0)
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Online");
```

The device I'm running on is a Samsung Galaxy S2, I'm targetting my laptop, a Macbook Pro running Fedora. Both devices are on the same WiFi network.

From my laptop I can detect and run an `nmap` scan on the Android phone (`192.168.0.3`). It's definitely reachable.

Comment: What's curious about getting ECONNREFUSED from a port that isn't open? That's exactly what you should expect.

Comment: @EJP What's curious is that the other ports are reporting that the destination can't be reached. If the destination can't be reached that would be the first error reported, for every port. You can't get a connection refused if you can't reach the target in the first place. Connection refused would mean that the target sent a `RST` flagged packet in response to `SYN`, IE: he was reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Could you please provide more details about your test?**

- What is your source device (android phone)?
- What destination are you trying to reach and scan? Computer on local or outside network?
- Are both source and destination devices on the same network (probably WiFi)?

**EHOSTUNREACH** - no route to host should say it is either

- ISO/OSI Layer 3 issue (devices on the different private IP networks
  without routes to each other)
- destination device is down
- ICMP protocol/ECHO replies are blocked somewhere in between (or
  firewall on source or destination device)

**ECONNREFUSED** - should be even more clear - this particular port is not opened on destination device

**Maybe you can split your code logic into two parts:**

1. Check if device is up and running (PING - ICMP protocol)
2. Then perform port scan

   - if isConnected == TRUE (port is open)
       else (port is closed)

**Output could be:**

1. PING is Successful && isConnected == TRUE (device is UP and port is
   OPEN)
2. PING is Successful && isConnected == FALSE (device is UP but port is
   CLOSED)
3. PING is Unsuccessful && isConnected == TRUE (probably ICMP protocol/ECHO request is BLOCKED - device is UP and port is OPENED)
4. PING is Unsuccessful && isConnected == FALSE (device is probably
   DOWN or ICMP is BLOCKED and port is CLOSED)

Try to give it a try.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Damian, thanks for the help, I've updated with some more information that hopefully explains some things. The phone is definitely reachable from my laptop, they're on the same subnet. I'm suspecting the `host unreachable` error is not "legitimate".

Comment: Hi Juicy, you are welcome - do you have Wireshark installed on destination (fedora) computer? Can you start packet capture while running your android port scanner app (we can check what is going on on the network) with filter:
ip.addr == 192.168.0.10

Comment: Hey Damian! It's definitely some network issue, I just tried scanning Google and got expected results (80 and 443 open). I'm now thinking it may be Fedora's firewall? Either way I'll have to leave investigations to later and get on with the work. Thanks again!

Comment: That's great! You are welcome. Yes it can be either network issue (firewall / iptables) or FTP issue - did you know FTP uses two ports? Data Channel (port 20 or random) and command channel port 21? Anyway I'm happy it work for you as expected for other hosts. Happy coding! :) FTP simplified: http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/80512/Active-v-s-Passive-FTP-Simplified

Comment: `isConnnected()` doesn't have the magical properties frequently ascribed to it. All it tells you is whether you have called `connect()` successfully, explicitly or implicitly. The way to detect connect failures is via `ConnectException.`